# What to do on a new build

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I just build my new computer and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on the SSD. Now as this is the first time using Ubuntu, I really need some advice on how to get this working together:

First problem: My screen native resolution isn't listed in the available resolution. Screen: benQ GW2270hw, native resolution: 1920x1080.

Second problem: I don't know how to install the NVIDIA drivers, I think the machine doesn't even detect the GPU (GTX 1050). If I type lspci | grep VGA it returns:
 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c81 (rev a1)

Third problem: I need to be able to install my internet on Ubuntu. It's a vodaphone usb stick and it doesn't get detected when plugged in the new build.

Some detailed help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: internet is now working

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to:

- First problem: Because the proper drivers are not installed.
- Drivers can be installed in two ways:

  - [First method](https://askubuntu.com/a/201524/119531) is via Software Sources.
  - [Second method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZ-r3gS38RU) is relevant if you want the latest driver (even if it is in beta/alpha).
- Third problem: You need to check if the vendor even supports linux or not.

---

[Link](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/118524) to get your driver for NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (NOT 1050Ti).

Comment: I'm trying to install the laterst NVIDIA drivers for the GTX 1050, but I can't follow the first method you listed since it says ''No additional drivers available''. Probably due to the fact that the PC is not connected to the internet yet.

Comment: @TimoKerr - Yes, it shows that because it is not connected to the internet.

Comment: @TimoKerr - What is you usb modem model number?

Comment: What I can read off is: model : K4505 and FCC ID: QISCP12V

Comment: Also, Raphael, when I downloaded the .run file for the Nvidia drivers, can I just execute them on Ubuntu? I'm doing that now, but somewhere it seems to have problems reading it...

Comment: so I'm now trying to get my internet working before anything else, however it seems that the USB dongle doesn't work.

Comment: @TimoKerr - Did you install the drivers? Have the issues relating to graphics drivers been resolved?

Comment: @TimoKerr - If this answer solved your issue then please upvote the answer by clicking on ⌃ icon beside the answer and then accept the answer by clicking on the ✔ present below the above icon.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, all issues are resolved. New problems have arisen but I will try to figure them out.